# How to make a one line sentence animated with css text animation responsive?

Tags: html, webkit, css-animations

I'm trying to make a one line sentence which is animated with css text animation responsive.
On a full screen it's working fine. As soon as I shrink the screen, the text line continues instead of splitting into two lines.

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes typing { from { width: 0; } }
@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret { 50% { border-color: transparent; } }

.header-text h1 { 
    font: bold 100% Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
    border-right: .1em solid black;
    width: auto;
    width: 75ch;
    margin-top: 1em;    
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-animation: typing 6s steps(100, end),
               blink-caret .5s step-end infinite alternate; 
}
```

Comment: Note that no browser has needed the `-webkit` vendor prefix in many years.